# The right key input handling

Tags: java, input, 2d-games

Hello :) I'm trying to find the efficient way to handle java key input. I have this piece of code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   if (checkInput) {
       switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
           case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
               arrow[LEFT] = true; // boolean for my key input 
               checkInput = false;
           break;
           case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
               arrow[RIGHT] = true;
               checkInput = false;
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

and then:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
           switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
               case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                   arrow[LEFT] = false; // boolean for my key input 
                   checkInput = true;
               break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                   arrow[RIGHT] = false;
                   checkInput = true;
               break;
           }
       }
    }
```

my point is when I press left or right function keyPressed would stop checking key input but it's not working ... in main class i have constructor:

```
public Game() {

        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                player.keyReleased(e); // function mentioted above are from Player class. 

            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                player.keyPressed(e);

            }

        });
        setFocusable(true);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear what the question is. But perhaps you want (!keys) for the test for the release case? Otherwise, the "keys=true" statement is not changing anything in the keyReleased segment.

Comment: What is `keys`, what is `key[]` and what is `LEFT`?

Comment: I start the game and keys is true. then i press left or right and keys is false so it shouldn't check other keys pressed. and then if I release left or right key, variable keys gets true so keyPressed is working again. but it doesn't work

Comment: i have edited it, becouse there were too many keys

Answer (score 0):

If you want my opinion, don't try to stop other keys from pressing while a key is pressed. This seems to be a user-specified task (pressing multiple keys), and unless it has direct harm towards your game, you should put all this effort into a reasonless limitation.

```
public boolean[] keys = new boolean[200]; //just enough to hold all key codes

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
     keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}
```

Now, you can move depending on what key is pressed.

```
while(true) {
     if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT]) {
          //move right
     }
}
```

But, if you REALLY want this limitation:

```
public boolean[] keys = new boolean[200]
public boolean acceptEvents = true;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     if(acceptEvents) {
          keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
          acceptEvents = false;
     }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
     keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
     acceptEvents = true;
}
```

It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do with the limited resources you gave us (you left out a lot of things in your code example), so let me know if this helped or not